# Which process is preventing me using Wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, linux, networking, android-tv, pppoe

I have a TV box provided by ISP (also TV channels provider), which has Android 4.4.4 Linux kernel 3.10.23. (I have root already)

It uses PPPoE to get a network so can receive TV stream, but this network has no Internet.
It also has wifi, which **only works when PPPoE is down**.

**I want to make PPPoE and wifi work simultaneously, so get both TV stream and Internet.** I did some test and find out there must be some process preventing wifi when PPPoE is on.

I use Linux laptop to setup an AP. I make box connect to AP on box's setting layout, when PPPoE on. I see this on Linux:

```
ap0: STA 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: authenticated
ap0: STA 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
ap0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx
ap0: STA 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx RADIUS: starting accounting session E67960Dxxxxx
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPDISCOVER(ap0) 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx 
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPOFFER(ap0) 192.168.7.125 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx 
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPREQUEST(ap0) 192.168.7.125 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx 
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPACK(ap0) 192.168.7.125 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx FF1004xxxxxx
ap0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 74:97:81:xx:xx:xx
```

Connection sucessfully established, and even box has got IP from DHCP (I also see IP on TV for a very short time). Then soon disconnected.

If I unplug the cable, or turn Ethernet off in box's settings, or set a wrong PPPoE password, the wifi works.

How do I find out which process it preventing wifi?